# Is there any trick to solve system of linear equations by Row Equivalent Method?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Whenever I try to solve three equations (having x, y and z) variables, I never get to the solution. Sometimes, complex fractions are formed during the process, sometimes large numbers and even if I make the matrix a unit matrix, the answers are incorrect... Is there any way (trick) to get the notion of the correct steps or somehow get to the correct answer (without having to think for long)?

Comment: I've [edit]ed away the capital title.

Comment: The algorithm for row reduction is just that - an step by step process that when done correctly has been proved to lead the the correct answer. There is no other general "trick". If you edit the question to show us a particular calculation that you got wrong we may be able to help you. (There is never a guarantee that you won't get fractions or large numbers, though they are often avoided by textbook authors.) Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference